# Mixing in Odata messes up custom System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, authorize-attribute

We have a Web Api application that's been working for a long time.

We have implemented our own `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` to initialize our user state and role providers, and during our overload of **IsAuthorized()** we set `HttpContext.Current.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to our own `GenericPrincipal` initialized with all our stuff.

That's been working fine a long time.

Now we've been asked to stand up some Odata apis, so we fetched v6.15 from git, and it's dragged along a lot of other dlls (newer/different mvc dlls for example) that have changed the behavior of how `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` actions fit in the pipeline.

Now, while our `[Authorize (Roles="OurFoo")]` correctly authorizes, Thread.CurrentPrincipal is getting reset/swapped out with something else before we actually get into our method.  That's breaking

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "OurFoo")]
```

permissions lower down in our callstack.

Has anyone else run into this and figured the proper workaround?

I've found Stack articles about using `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` as a base instead of `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` but the signatures are different and it was unclear if that would do anything about the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` getting reset issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone has a better answer (other than telling me to re-write the entire app "the new way") but I found a work around.

I broke up our authentication logic from our authorization in our IsAuthorized() function and put it in a MessageHandler, hoping that would get processed early enough in the pipeline that setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal would persist.  That appeared to work.